# Did Kaurav's son participate in the Mahabharata battle?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kauravas, chandravansh

In Mahabharata we have read/heard and seen in television shows that when the Mahabharata battle took place, all Pandava's son (i.e Abhimanyu and the rest) participated.

But did Duryodhana & other Kaurav's son participate in the Mahabharata battle or they didn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duryodhana#Family),

> Duryodhana was married to Bhanumati, daughter of Bhagadatta, king of
>   the city Pragjyotisha. He fathered two children of royal queen, son
>   *Laxman Kumara* and daughter *Lakshmana* and many children from concubines as well. As per Urubhanga he had a son called Durjay of who
>   information is not yet known.

[Laxman](http://www.encyclopediaindica.com/index.php/Lakshmana) was [killed by Abhimanyu in the Mahabharata war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laxman_Kumara#Death) on the 13<sup>th</sup> day using the Nagashirashtra.